# Is there a way to convert a csv file to a space sperated file in python

Tags: python

How can I convert a csv file into a space separated file in python (or using other languages or method if needed)?

So I want to have:

```
1,2,3,4
5,6,7,8
```

be converted into:

```
1 2 3 4
5 6 7 8
```

Thank you!

Comment: What did you try, and how was it deficient?

Comment: I'd just use sed for something that simple...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For fun, here it is in one line:

```
open('out.csv', 'w').write('\n'.join(map(' '.join, __import__('csv').reader(open('in.csv')))))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could read it, replace the commas with spaces and write the output to a new file:

```
with open ('commas.txt') as input_file:
    s = input_file.read().replace(',', ' ')
    with open ('spaces.txt', 'w') as output_file:
        output_file.write(s)
```

Note that such a naive implementation may cause problems if the file is very large, as it's all read to memory at once. If the file is indeed too large, a chunked approach, perhaps reading line by line would be recommended.